# Dropping OID column with ArcPy Table To Excel?

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, excel

Using ArcPy in a script, I'm exporting a table to Excel (using Table To Table and Table to Excel).

Is there a way or workaround to get rid of the Object ID column in the export process?

I'd like to avoid using the Python Excel modules.

Answer (score 7):

1. [Make Table View](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-table-view.htm) with ObjectID unchecked:
   [image]
2. [Run Table To Excel](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/table-to-excel.htm) with the table view as input

Comment: I always forget about the Make Table View tool.  This is a much simpler solution to what I was going to suggest.

Comment: @DanielSE Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our format.  If this has answered your question, please consider marking it as the answer by clicking on the Check-mark under the voting buttons on the left.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).